# HTML - Table Content Alignment

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on a web based game. I have made the navigation but the text is not aligned correctly.

**HTML**

```
 <table width="123" height="253" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="table">   <tr>
 <td height="23" class="header">Main Game</td>   </tr>   <tr>
 <td height="65" valign="top" class="cell" align="center">  <a href="home.php">Homepage</a>     <a href="staff.php">Staff Page</a>
 </td>   </tr>   <tr>
 <td height="23" class="header">Social</td>   </tr>   <tr>
 <td height="65" valign="top" class="cell"><a href="forum.php">Discussions</a></td>   </tr>   <tr>
 <td height="23" class="header">LogOut</td>   </tr> </table>
```

**CSS**

```
 .table { 
   border:#000000 1px solid; background-color:#363636; 
 }

 .cell { 
   color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px; background-color:#1C1C1C; align:center; 
 }

 .header { 
   padding:0px; padding-left:2px; color:#FFFFFF;
   background:#3A0D07; font-family:verdana; font-size:10px;
   line-height:18px; text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid;
   border-color:#000000; align:center;
 }
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your code, the anchor tags are displayed `inline-block` by default

a quick fix for your code is to change the display for the `a` tags, add the following to your css:

```
.table .a{
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tables you should use list item as they render the same in every browser. Also you have better control over if.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li>Home</li>
 <li>Stuff</li>
 <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
}
```